# PHPUnit: Probar una clase que llama a otra clase

Tags: php, composer, phpunit

Tengo una clase con un constructor como este:

```
class ClassA {

       public function __construct( $plugin_name, $version ) {

        $this->plugin_name = $plugin_name;
        $this->version = $version;
        $this->enrollment= new ClassB( $this );

    }
}
```

Y la claseB como:

```
class classB{

    public function __construct( $parent ) {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }
}
```

La clase A tiene una función que llama a una función de la clase B y esa función es la que quiero probar, el flujo de llamada de las funciones es:

```
class ClassA {

       public function register_enrollment_custom_post_type(){
        $this->enrollment->classB_function();
    }
}

class classB{

    public function classB_function(){
        //anything
    }
}
```

¿Cómo puede pensar que puedo probar con PHPUnit y compositor que classB_function()?

He intentado crear una instancia usando new ClassA() de classA pero me da un error: Clase "classB" no encontrada de esta forma (solo para probar si ejecutaba):

```
public function testGreeterSaysHello() {
        $admin = new ClassA("name", "1.0.0");
    }
```

Con los respectivos use para invocar los archivos que contienen las clases.